# Why is pyinstaller sensitive to working directory?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm building an application with PyInstaller, and I get different behaviors depending on the directory from which I run the application. For example:

```
user:~$ ./project/dist/runmyapp
<fails>

user:~$ /home/user/project/dist/runmyapp
<fails>

user:~$ cd project

user:~/project$ ./dist/runmyapp
<runs correctly>

user:~/project$ /home/user/project/dist/runmyapp
<runs correctly>
```

When it fails, I get a bizarre unicode error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 330, in find_cookie
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 128: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runmyapp", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module

<lots of stack trace> 

  File "traceback.py", line 197, in format_stack
  File "traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
  File "traceback.py", line 366, in extract
  File "traceback.py", line 288, in line
  File "linecache.py", line 16, in getline
  File "linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
  File "linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
  File "tokenize.py", line 394, in open
  File "tokenize.py", line 371, in detect_encoding
  File "tokenize.py", line 335, in find_cookie
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '/home/user/project/dist/runmyapp'
[7407] Failed to execute script 'runmyapp' due to unhandled exception!
```

If you look at the bytes of the actual executable (./dist/runmyapp, produced by pyinstaller), it is true that byte 128 is 0xa8:

```
00000080: a802 0000 0000 0000 a802 4000 0000 0000  ..........@.....
          ^^
```

But that's going to be the case no matter what the working directory is when it gets run. And also, it's an executable, so the python interpreter shouldn't be trying to read it like a script file (my understanding is that the executable is pyinstaller's "bootloader").

That leads me to believe that I'm running the executable, and it is trying to read a file at a path relative to my current working directory, and that just happens to be the executable itself. That's strange, since my own code would never reference an executable that doesn't exist yet (i.e., before pyinstaller builds it), and also, the target path should change as I move directories, but it seems to fail in all but one location.

There are plenty of mentions on SO of `UnicodeDecodeError` related to pyinstaller, but it seems to be a different issue. I'm stuck, since I don't get enough information from the stack trace about why it's trying to read `runmyapp` like it's a script.

Has anyone seen similar behavior? Any insights? Thanks!

### Edit 07/12/2023

Here is a minimal reproducible example. I am using python 3.8.10 and pyinstaller 5.13.0.

File tree:

```
/
    /pyitest/
        /pyitest/__init__.py
        /pyitest/__main__.py
    /runtest
    /setup.py
```

__main__.py:

```py
import traceback


def main():
    traceback.print_stack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

runtest:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pyitest.__main__ import main


main()
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

package_name = 'pyitest'

setup(name=package_name,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    setup_requires='wheel',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'runtest = pyitest.__main__:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

To build:

```bash
$ mktemp -d ./pyibuild.XXXXXX
./pyibuild.3TbKYF
$ cp runtest ./pyibuild.3TbKYF/
$ python setup.py build
$ pyi-makespec --paths build/lib ./pyibuild.3TbKYF/runtest 
$ pyinstaller runtest.spec
```

To run:

```bash
$ ./dist/runtest/runtest` (works fine)
$ cd ..
$ <project_root>/dist/runtest/runtest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 330, in find_cookie
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 40: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtest", line 6, in <module>
  File "pyitest/__main__.py", line 5, in main
  File "traceback.py", line 190, in print_stack
  File "traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
  File "traceback.py", line 366, in extract
  File "traceback.py", line 288, in line
  File "linecache.py", line 16, in getline
  File "linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
  File "linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
  File "tokenize.py", line 394, in open
  File "tokenize.py", line 371, in detect_encoding
  File "tokenize.py", line 335, in find_cookie
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '<project_root>/dist/runtest/runtest'
[44713] Failed to execute script 'runtest' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: This is speculative right now, but if we were to determine that the issue couldn't be reproduced with a specific alternate Python interpreter release and alternate pyinstaller build, would you accept a known-working set of tools as an answer, or is the focus really on getting a root cause for the issue as observed in the releases described?

Comment: Well, I just tested it a moment ago on Arch (python 3.11.3), and it does not behave this way. Unfortunately I'm hamstrung by Ubuntu (Focal) on our target system, which ships python 3.8.10. I would like to understand the root cause if possible so I can find a workaround for our target system.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a workaround, but I can confirm that python 3.9 behaves the same way, and python 3.10 is fixed.